# Why wpf dynamic tabs don't show more than first header?

Tags: wpf, dynamic, tabcontrol

I want to dynamically add and remove tabs from a wpf TabControl only via databinding. Here is the example XAML:

```
<Window x:Name="UI_MainWindow" x:Class="DynamicTabs.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DynamicTabs"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI_MainWindow, Mode=OneWay}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="Add Tab" Click="Click_AddTab"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <TabControl x:Name="UI_TabControl" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Tabs}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And here the code behind:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace DynamicTabs
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
        public List<TabItem> Tabs { get; set; }
        public TabItem SelectedTab { get; set; }
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Tabs=new List<TabItem>();
        }
        private void Click_AddTab(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TabItem newTab=new TabItem();
            newTab.Header="Tab"+(Tabs.Count+1).ToString();
            Tabs.Add(newTab);
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Tabs));
            SelectedTab=newTab;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedTab));
        }
    }
}
```

The behaviour is like this:
First click on "Add Tab": one tab is shown with header "Tab1"
Any further clicks on "Add Tab": the items of the TabControl are increased, also the SelectedItem seems to be updated, but no new headers are drawn.

I tried a workaround (see https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/493538/Add-Remove-Tabs-Dynamically-in-WPF) by setting the DataContext of the TabControl programmatically, which works.
However, i would like to understand, why my version does not work.

Comment: Well, you certainly can't update `SelectedTab` like you're doing without raising `PropertyChanged`. Did you just omit that for brevity? And `Tabs` needs to be `ObservableCollection<TabItem>`, not `List`. Otherwise how is the `TabControl` supposed to know anything changed?

Comment: You should not be implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` on a window, and it's usually a very bad idea to have a List or ObservableCollection of a control type like `TabItem`, but `TabControl` is kind of a special case with that rule, because *mumble mumble virtualization*.

Answer (score 1):

> However, i would like to understand, why my version does not work.

Because you are binding to a `List<TabItem>` instead of an `ObservableCollection<TabItem>`. If you simply change the type of the source collection it works:

```
public ObservableCollection<TabItem> Tabs { get; set; }
public TabItem SelectedTab { get; set; }
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Tabs = new ObservableCollection<TabItem>();
}
```

The difference between the two collection types is that the latter implements the [INotifyCollectionChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface. Implementing this interface is required if you want the `ItemsControl` in the view to get updated automatically when you add or remove an item to or from the source collection.